# Relativistic length contraction

Tags: special-relativity

A moving object will have relativistic length contraction.
About which point on the object would it contract?
For instance, would the contraction be towards the point on the object that is closest to the observer?

Comment: I agree that it will be contracted in the direction parallel to the motion. My question is about the point about which the contraction takes place.

Comment: What on earth does this mean?  According to me, at any given moment, the front of my rocket ship is 100 meters from the back.  According to you, at any given moment, the front of my rocket ship is 80 meters from the back.  From those data, how do you define a "point about which the ship is contracted"?

Answer (score 2):

The only well-defined point around which to define contraction is the center of the object along its direction of motion. This value is independent of the apparent length of the object. Additionally, the contraction has nothing to do with the direction that points towards the observer. The object will only be contracted along the spatial dimension in which it is traveling. So, if it is a rod traveling along its axis, it will not change in radius.

Comment: Agreed that the object will contract along the spatial dimension in which it is traveling. Agreed that a rod will not change radius. However, what is the proof that it contracts about it's center? Also, how do you define center here? Is it the center of gravity? Is it the geometric center?

Comment: In my question, I am referring to the point on the object along the axis of motion that is closest to the observer

Comment: If you are correct about the contraction being at the center, then would a very long object accelerating away from an observer have it's closer end accelerating faster than the center due to length contraction?

Comment: Contraction does not depend on a point; it occurs to the same degree regardless of the central point, and only depends on the velocity. Because the geometrical center is the only thing that is also independent of velocity and/or contraction, it represents the “center” when discussing Lorentz contractions. The center is the only geometrical invariant. Even when the length changes, the center moves along as always. Unlike general relativity, length in special relativity does NOT take mass into account.

Comment: I know that contraction occurs to the same degree regardless of the central point. However, your statements do not prove that it contracts about a geometric center. If this is the case, then if an object had most of its mass concecentated in a high density sphere; attached to the sphere is low density very long pole (center of mass in the sphere and geometric center in the pole), then how does the geometric center contraction make sense?

Comment: Suppose a hypothetical object is a planet with an attached very long hypothetical pole many thousand times the diameter of the planet (the hypothetical pole has an ultra low density). The pole is long enough that the geometric center is located inside the pole. Of course, this is a hypothetical imaginary case, but if this object moves along the axis of the pole, would it contract about the geometric center?

Comment: I don't think so

Comment: Lorentz contractions don’t give a **** about mass. The only other thing to care about is length. No matter how many times you length contract your sphere and rod, the geometric center will be the same (different, depending on how long you make your rod). The point is that once you choose the lengths, the geometric center is constant. The center of mass is totally irrelevant. Imagine shrinking things to a point. You’ll always hit the same center. Expand them, and the geometric center will be the same. It doesn’t matter how much you send to left or right from that point.

Comment: Furthermore, length contraction is defined between two events. Your scenario does not define two clear instances of measuring lengths at specificied locations and times.

Comment: Forget mass. Assume a long rod is moving along it's axis. According to your hypothesis, relative to any stationary observer it contracts about the geometric center. Assume now there is an observer moving at the same speed as the rod and he cuts the rod in half. According to the moving observer the two halves move together without a gap on the cut. Relative to a stationary observer, the two halves would contract about their new geometric centers, forming a gap about the cut. How does this make sense?

Comment: No, that is not the case. You have changed your initial argument from one object to two objects by cutting the first in half. Neither experienced any change in perceived length as a result of the cutting. This is why I said you just refer to particular events. The moment that one end of a rod passes, to the moment the other end of the same rod passes. If you compare these events, it will work out. Absolute lengths of objects are not well-defined; only the proper lengths and proper times between events.

Comment: Ok. Agreed about using relativity of simultaneity to work this paradox out. However, your statement of contraction about geometric center is falsified in this case. If there is no gap formed relative to a stationary observer, then these 2 halves are no longer contracted about their geometric centers.

Comment: The issue is that rigid objects are not the concern of special relativity. Rather, the spacetime distance between two events provides the basis of length. “Event” can mean the moment at which a certain section of a rod passes a certain location. Thinking of the “size” of a thing, instead of where a certain part of the thing is at a certain time, can lead to to confusion in relativity.

Comment: As long as you refer to the the front end of the rod passing a point as event 1, and the back end of the second segment of the severed rod as event 2, there is no difference in whether the rod is cut or not. They are not contracted about their respective geometric centers, but they are contracted about the geometric center between the event of the front end of the rod and the back end of the rod. The geometric center argument applies to two events.

Comment: Relevant to special relativity or not. The fact of the matter remains that a stationary observer should be able to measure the point about which a moving object contracts. If it is the geometric center, then cutting the object in half would falsify the geometric center contraction principle.

Comment: According to the principles that define length contraction, there are no extended objects.

Comment: Since you brought events into the picture. Forget the event of cutting. The observer no longer cuts the object. We bring 2 separate rods in contact with each other and accelerate them to a given velocity along their axis. Do they contract about their geometric centers?

Comment: It really doesn’t matter whether there is one rod, two rods, or a billion rods. It matters which two points you want to compare. As soon as you try to compare segments of more than one rod, you’re trying to compare more than two events. Special relativity defines quanties between two events at a time. You can handle multiple events sequentially, or deal with them one by one. Geometric centers make sense if you talk about one object.

Comment: According to that argument, 2  identical rockets attached together by a thin long wire can be regarded as one object, and thus length contraction will happen at the geometric center, which is the midpoint of the thin wire. Nearby, there are another set of identical rockets separated by the same distance but without the thin wire connecting them. These rockets will contract about their geometric centers. Making these 2 cases appear drastically different to a stationary observer, just because of a thin wire. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The contraction is toward the front. The reason it appears to be contracted when travelling away (or you away from it) is that the light from the back has less distance to travel, so the back is seen moving before the front, & appears to partly catch up to it, making the object look shorter. L'/L= 1-v/c the same as Doppler formula for frequency. The same is true if the object is travelling cross ways. Light coming out at an angle towards the back intercepts the observer like if you throw a rock from a moving vehicle at a pole while passing it (you have to throw it partly backwards), so again, the light from the back has less distance to travel. L'/L=√(1-(v/c)²) (Lorentz Contraction). The light coming out backward also makes the object look partly turned away (the light you see is from it's rear end). If it is moving towards you (or you towards it), it would appear longer because the front would be seen moving first. L'/L=1+v/c